# How to check if querySnapshot is empty from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check if the querySnapShot is empty. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
function getOrders(userid) {
  db.collection("users").doc(userid).collection("bestellungen").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    if(querySnapshot is empty) {
      console.log("nichts");
    }
    else {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
    }

});
}
```

Looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the [`empty`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot?authuser=0#empty) property, as follows:

```
//....
if(querySnapshot.empty) {
  console.log("nichts");
} else {
//....
```